# How to enable Java assertions in jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, jetty, assertions

How to enable [assertions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) in [jetty-maven-plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin)? By default they are disabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` to `-ea`. Jetty by default runs within Maven process and thus is affected by this setting.

There is also interesting library called [Force Assertions](http://scg.unibe.ch/wiki/alumni/adriankuhn/javacompiler/forceassertions) which hooks into Java 1.6 compilation process. During compilation all `assert cond : detail;` are transparently compiled to `if (!cond) throw new Assertion(detail);` blocks, which means assertions will work always no matter what JVM parameters are. Worth to check.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same inside `pom.xml`?

Comment: I'm afraid not, jetty plugin doesn't have fork setting, where you can set its JVM configuration separately.

Comment: forceassertions is interesting indeed. anyone know how to use it with maven?

Answer (score 0):

See: [maven jetty plugin - how to control vm arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007192/maven-jetty-plugin-how-to-control-vm-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Netbeans (tested with Netbeans 8.0), this is the way to do it imo:

Add this to your nbactions.xml file (in the project root directory):

```
<actions>
  <action>
    <actionName>CUSTOM-jetty:run</actionName>
    <displayName>jetty:run</displayName>
    <goals>
        <goal>jetty:run</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
        <Env.MAVEN_OPTS>-ea</Env.MAVEN_OPTS>
    </properties>
  </action>
</actions>
```

No other setup needed. You can just use jetty:run.

See also https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=166874

Answer (score 0):

If it's to only run tests and you are using maven-surefire-plugin, use this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```