# maven jetty plugin - running as daemon - how to control vm arguments?

Tags: maven-2, maven-jetty-plugin

I am running Jetty during some integration tests in daemon mode and am getting an out-of-memory error. So I'd like to set the heap size to something substantial. This question is a bit like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007192/maven-jetty-plugin-how-to-control-vm-arguments) except I am running in daemon mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```