# Jacoco w/ Jetty + Selenium RC

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-jetty-plugin, jacoco

I come back here because I have some kind of problem. (I posted 2 or 3 questions before about a project I'm working on, this question is still related to this project)
So I have a smartGWT webapplication which I build using Maven. To unit test it, I had to use Selenium RC (to be able to use the user-extensions.js provided by smartClient), and as it must be compatible with the continuous integration, I had to deploy the webapp on a Jetty container. Now I only got one problem left :
**How can I use Jacoco with Jetty to make Sonar recognize my tests and give me code coverage ?**

Is there a property in the jetty-maven-plugin that allows me to run the jacoco-agent each time the application is deployed ?

Thanks in advance, one more time =)
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: you need to attach the javagent at the start of the jetty server, when deployment happens the server is already running

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven jetty plugin - how to control vm arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007192/maven-jetty-plugin-how-to-control-vm-arguments)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate, I know how to pass an argument to the JVM (I already do it), though I don't know how to use the jacoco agent with Jetty. It is launched but Sonar does not recognize my code coverage (jacoco is installed on the sonar server) so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: the duplicate tells you how you can add an jvm argument (i.e. jacoco agent) to maven. If you start jetty in Maven you need to set the jacoco agent to maven. Do you know how the jacoco java agent works normally?

Comment: Yeah except your "duplicate" doesn't really help me. I don't want to set a global JVM arg, but simply add some args to my jetty start. I've seen that cargo can do it (`<cargo.jvmargs>`). Though I already added so much things on that project that I don't want to use ANOTHER thing such as cargo since I configured all the jetty environment. So I was asking how to start jacoco agent with jetty... Not how to add a global parameter to the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your only option is the cargo plugin.

As described in the link to the duplicated question Jetty is executed in the same JVM as Maven.

So if JVM options are not possible you have to use the cargo plugin.

Comment: What about starting Jacoco with Surefire during the pre-integration-phase ? I think it works because Surefire as a <argline> tag.

Comment: For surefire there is the jacoco maven plugin. If your testcases would start the server themselves it would work. Basically you need a maven plugin that starts a new JVM, that you can configure via args.

Comment: I do use the jacoco maven plugin. I think now it's working. Though I still don't get code coverage (even if the sensor is working in Jenkins)

Comment: Perhaps you should try to geth this solved by using the sonar mailing list, this topic my be hard to track and SO is not suited for that kind of stuff :)

Comment: and are you using a current version of sonar or something with version < 2.12 (where jacoco only works if you install the plugin manually)

Comment: I'm using Sonar 2.10 and the plugin is installed.

Comment: maybe update to the newest version where jacoco is fully integrated and in newer version.

Answer (score 0):

The maven-jetty-plugin has recently added support for running jetty in a separate JVM, ala cargo, so you might be in luck: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-991. Otherwise you can use cargo (that is what I do).