# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen (GWT + NetBeans + Maven)

Tags: maven, gwt

I am working on GWT + NetBeans + Maven project and I keep getting out of memory error. I am running the project simply by executing **gwt:debug** goal.

I tried to set higher memory limits in pom.xml like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <modules>
                            <module>cz.bull.iui.User</module>
                            <!--<module>cz.bull.iui.Login</module>-->
                        </modules>
                        <localWorkers>4</localWorkers>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024M -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M</extraJvmArgs>
                        <localWorkers>4</localWorkers>
                        <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                        <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                        <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
                        <style>OBF</style>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But the problem still occurs:

[image: GWT development Mode console]
Could some advise me, where do I have to set it, so GWT gets enough memory? By checking Task manager I can see Development Mode console is using about 500MB at the occurrence of crash, which is less than defined.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe if you try with 'm' instead of 'M'? (like -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m), huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only good answer is to switch to Eclipse, it just doesn't work with NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below link where a lots of the ways are suggested to set the vm arguments in `Jetty`.

- [maven jetty plugin - how to control vm arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007192/maven-jetty-plugin-how-to-control-vm-arguments)

Comment: I use NetBeans in this case.

Comment: I don't think throwing random topics on me is gonna help me. Believe me, I did some research myself. Why do you think this is a problem of NetBeans, GWT Development Mode/Jetty is running in it's own process I think. Did some of those helped you with GWT project on NetBeans?

Comment: There is no way this is gonna work, GWT is not running inside NetBeans process.

Comment: GWT application is running in Jetty in DEV mode and I have already shared you a link to set the arguments of Jetty itself. There is lots of response. Please check the answer given by @Binita Bharati. Set `MAVEN_OPTS`

Comment: Follow the link carefully and read all the response. You will definitely get the answer.

Comment: I have the MAVEN_OPTS stetted (-Xmx1024m) but the problem still remains.