# Dataproc: SSL certificate not found for Sqoop job connecting to external PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, sqoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to connect to PostgreSQL db via SSL. I received 2 certificates and 1 key -> sslrootcert=root.crt sslcert=postgresql.crt and sslkey=postgresql.key.der

Here is my import config from Dataproc:

```
import
-Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true
-Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/secrets/prod/db.jceks
--connect=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.x.x/DBNAME?sslrootcert=root.crt&sslcert=postgresql.crt&sslkey=postgresql.key.der
--username=user1
--table=db1
--target-dir=gs://bucket
--delete-target-dir
--as-avrodatafile
--password-alias=password
```

The Dataproc coundn't find my SSL certificates:
`Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL certificate file postgresql.crt`

How I could add certificates and key to dataproc to be sure that these certs be accessible in connection config.

Where I should store SSL certificates to use them in import config during run job :

```
--connect=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.x.x/DBNAME?sslrootcert=/???/??/root.crt&sslcert=/???/??/postgresql.crt&sslkey=/???/??/postgresql.key.der
```

Comment: Dataproc doesn't include PostgreSQL, are you trying to connect to an external PostgreSQL from Dataproc? Also what is the code snippet above? Is it a PySpark job?

Comment: @Dagang, yes I'm trying to run sqoop job to connect to an external PostgreSQL. The data need to be transferred from PostgreSQL to GCS bucket

Comment: @Dagang, I updated the comment a bit

Comment: I think you want to add it to Java's default certificates location, `${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts`, for Dataproc it is `/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add the server certificate or its root CA certificate to Dataproc VMs at `${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts`, for Dataproc it is `/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. You can use an init action or create a custom image to put the cert in the dir.

See this [doc](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37394078/how-to-connect-with-postgresql-database-over-ssl) for more details.