# Supply JVM args to command line "mvn scala:run"

Tags: scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to launch a Scala application with the `scala-maven-plugin`.  I can execute with

`mvn scala:run -DmainClass=... -DaddArgs=...`

but I would like to add JVM args to the command line as well.  It looks like this can be done with launch configuration in the POM, but I'd like to do it entirely from the command line.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525288/is-there-a-way-to-pass-jvm-args-via-command-line-to-maven, which in turn is marked a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007192/how-to-control-vm-arguments-for-maven-jetty-plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to pass jvm args via command line to maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525288/is-there-a-way-to-pass-jvm-args-via-command-line-to-maven)